# Saving activity state with photos loaded from phone?

Tags: android, bitmap, gallery, savestate

I've got an activity that takes photos from your gallery and put them on the screen, but when i exit the app and goes back they wont stay saved there. How do i save them in the activity when i exit and come back? 
Been trying with onSavedInstanceState but i got no clue what im doing anymore. Im kinda new to this. Here is my activity:

```
public class HatActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
LinearLayout main;
Bitmap b;
int count = 0;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle toSave) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(toSave);
    toSave.putParcelable("bitmap", b);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (savedInstanceState != null) b = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("bitmap");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hat);
    main = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main);

    getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.abc_textfield_search_right_default_holo_light));
    getActionBar().setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.abc_search_url_text_normal)));
}

public void infoClick(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        lparams.gravity=0x11;
        lparams.topMargin=60;
        lparams.bottomMargin=30;
        count++;
        BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);
        iv.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 480, 460, false));
        main.addView(iv, count, lparams);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your loading the images then tring to savestate the images.

You need to savestate the paths then reload the images. Unless your going to copy the images into a file (gallery) of your creation.  Which is bad in my opinion because of the space that would use up.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentScore);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(STATE_LEVEL, mCurrentLevel);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // Restore state members from saved instance
   mCurrentScore = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SCORE);
   mCurrentLevel = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_LEVEL);
}
```

Comment: see where you're saving the path here String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);  savestate that string  instead of the toSave.putParcelable("bitmap", b);    savestate is short for onSaveInstanceState

Comment: Ok i was trying something like this:

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putString("imagePath", picturePath);

        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
and 

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            picturePath = savedInstanceState.getString("imagePath");
        }
But it doesnt work. What am i missing?

Comment: Are you calling your if statement in your on create AND onRestore?   see http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html